# MySQL matches uuid against the primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, uuid

I am having a really bizarre issue with MySQL selecting undesired records. Here is my setup that should reproduce the issue.

**The Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**The Records**

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `uuid`)
VALUES
    (4, '23ee7c80-ce43-11e2-84b8-da3b984baf8c'),
    (12, '4bde3afe-ce30-11e2-9e98-b27639b9f5a0');
```

**The Query**

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = '4bde3afe-ce30-11e2-9e98-b27639b9f5a' LIMIT 1;
```

**The Result**

```
+----+--------------------------------------+
| id | uuid                                 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  4 | 23ee7c80-ce43-11e2-84b8-da3b984baf8c |
+----+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, it is selecting the wrong record. Any insight would be very appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks for your input. As it turns out it was type conversion playing tricks on me! Here is the warning MySQL was giving:

```
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                 |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '4bde3afe-ce30-11e2-9e98-b27639b9f5a' |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Wish I thought to check that earlier, but my client program (Sequel Pro) doesn't register warnings, only errors.. Oh well

Comment: it looks like you are filtering on the `id` column rather than the `uuid` column... which is weird cause based on your data you shouldn't be getting a result at all

Comment: What happens when you remove the limit? Also aren't you selecting where id = your uuid? Also what ChrisCamp said :)

Comment: what's the text of the warning that the result throws?

Comment: I'm aware I'm filtering on the wrong column. I came across this issue with a query I built that takes a mixed value and checks the id, uuid, and username for matches. The idea is to find the record by multiple means. I solved my particular issue by running some conditions in PHP rather than filtering on multiple columns.

Comment: @ChrisCamp Refer to my edit for the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, this is an issue with type converting, when you are comparing char with number, it takes only 4 from the string. This query, for example, returns correct result:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE cast(users.id as char) = '4bde3afe-ce30-11e2-9e98-b27639b9f5a0'
```

Comment: Yup just type conversion, read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html :)

Comment: This was my assumption. I will have to be more careful about filtering on multiple columns. I would have imagined MySQL to be more strict about type conversion in order to maintain fast query speeds..

Answer (score 1):

looks like you should be filtering by `UUID` instead. try...

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `users`.`uuid` = '4bde3afe-ce30-11e2-9e98-b27639b9f5a0'
```